# How to recognize a USB device as an existing COM port and not a new one?

Tags: c#, windows

I have hundreds of USB devices, all the same, that will be plugged into a computer ( production testing rig ).  However I don't want each device to install as a new device with device driver ( ie, no "Found new hardware", installing... ).  But rather for the device to be recognized as an existing device / COM port.

Ages ago I happened to come across some code to do this.  But for the life of me I can't find it. I remember its approach was that you could programaticaly configure windows so that when a device was plugged in you could let it match to an existing device based just on product/vendor ID.

So I'm wondering how to achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this question, I found what I was looking for, it's actually simpler than I remember.

For an existing device ( COM port ) that you want all similar devices to be detected as, you need to set the IgnoreHWSerNum registry entry on that device in the registry.

For official details, refer :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj649944(v=vs.85).aspx